# how to set Storage::disk('s3') config NOT in env but instead in a file?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

This might sound a bit weird.
I now `laravel` has a really good build in `Storage` for `s3` where we can enter or s3 settings inside of `filesystems.php` but is there a way NOT using the `filesystems.php` to setup the config?

For example, instead of putting the `aws keys` inside the `filesystems.php` instead I have another file within root or any other places.  I can open it up and get the `keys` properly BUT how can I then setup the config right before I call `Storage::disk('s3')->put();` without using any of the `config` file variables?

Please let me know if my question might be a bit hard to understand, it might be a bit hard to know why I needed to do it this way but due to some circumstances, not using the `filesystems.php`

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use config folder you can create a new file

for example

file name is storage.php

```
return [
'key' => 'value'
];
```

in controller
echo config('storage.key');

Comment: If I do it that way, how do I setup in `Storage::disk` for the configuration though?  I don't want to use `config('storage.key')` inside `filesystems.php` but instead, right before I use `Storage::disk('s3')`